# Propositional Logic Discrete Maths: P => Q |- (P^Q) v (¬P^¬Q) v (¬P ^Q)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I'm hard stuck I don't even know what assumption to take, I was thinking something of the following, maybe someone can help me in the right direction (P.S I can't use any lemmas only basics i.e. conjunction bi/implication disjunction negation introduction and elimination rules (i.e. cant use P^¬P |- Q or any other lemma), :

```
1) P=>Q
.
.
.
¬(P^Q) => ¬               (=> intro)
¬(P^Q) =>                 (=> intro)
¬¬(P^Q)                   (¬  intro)
(P^Q)                     (¬  elim)
(P^Q) v (¬P^¬Q) v (¬P ^Q) (v intro)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have asked many questions; many of them received more than one answer and you have never accepted an answer...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA How do I do that? I'll do them straight away since most were good!

Comment: The proof is similar to the one in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922221/p-%e2%86%92-q-v-q-%e2%86%92-r-fitch-style-proof) : assume the negation of the conclusion plus $P$ and $\lnot Q$ and find all the necessary contradictions to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Case P.  Then P and Q.
Case not P.
. . Subcase not Q.  Thus not P and not Q.
. . Subcase Q,  Thus not P and Q.